# CreateProcess: space in a python command passed with -c

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I am trying to port muon (a C99 implementation of meson) to Windows, and i have some problem with one of its unit tests. This unit test calls python3 with an array of C string, this array being:

```
"-c"
"print("some output")"
```

Note that this array can be any python script passed to the interpreter.

So I call CreateProcess() with `lpApplicationName` being the string `"C:\Documents\msys2\mingw64\bin/python3.exe"` and `lpCommandLine` being `"-c print(\"some output\")"` (I have prepended `\` before each `"` that I find in the string in the above array)

My problem is the space that is in the print() function. I get this error message:

```
err failed to run python3:   File "<string>", line 1
    print("some
          ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)
```

I can't find a way to modify the string `print(\"some output\")` so that `lpCommandLine` is correctly built.

Does someone have an idea how to do this ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user (I can't remember the name) removed his answer and suggested to add `"` around each option, and it worked. So I built the C string :

```c
"\"-c\" \"print(\\"some output\\")\""
```

and the tests were successful (except the last one, but this latter is related to `lpEnvironment` argument of `CreateProcess()`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `"print('some output')"` or `'print("some output")'`?